# jquery mobile transition error loading page

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

Im using jquery mobile and im trying to use the transition effect, but when I try whit an external link on my same site, i gt an d error saying "error loading page".
This is the piece of code im using

```
<a href="test1.html" data-transition="pop">Slide to Page Two</a>
```

and if a change my link to a link on the page work fine.

```
<a href="#test1" data-transition="pop">Slide to Page Two</a>
```

Comment: make sure the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Linking to another page will cause the entire page to be loaded separately from the current page. Since JavaScript only runs in the scope of the current page, it cannot transition to new pages in the same way as local pages.

Comment: they are local page, but are different files like, from test.html linking to test1.html

Comment: It doesn't matter if they're both local. As long as they are different files they cannot transition like you can transition using #anchors that stay on the same page.

Comment: jQM is different, it loads external pages into DOM via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You should set ajax reference to false.

```
data-ajax="false"
```

Now your code works but without transition effect because transition effect works with ajax loader.